# retrieve bound object of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Is there any way to retrieve the object, that is bound to a function as `thisArg`?

Like:

```
let object = {};
let fn = function () {
    return 'hello world';
}
fn = fn.bind(object);

//now i want a way to achieve that this comparison results in true
let result = (object === fn.getBoundThis());
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there's nothing built into JavaScript that provides that information. `fn` itself would need to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

This approach can be helpful if you are able to modify `fn` function definition. Otherwise I don't see any way to get it.

```js
let object = {a:10};
let fn = function () {
    getThisVal(this);
    return;
}
let theObject;
let getThisVal = function(val){
    theObject = val
}
fn = fn.bind(object);
fn();
console.log(theObject);
```

**One more way can be instead of returning this you can call any other function defined by you inside `fn` and pass `this` as parameter and access it there.**

Answer (score 0):

Like other answers mention, there is no built-in way.

But you can wrap the bind method and intercept the bound object:

```js
// this should be the first javascript 
// that you execute on the page
(function() {
  let originalBind = Function.prototype.bind;

  //wrap bind function
  Function.prototype.bind = function(obj) {
    let boundFunction = originalBind.call(this, obj);
    boundFunction.boundThis = obj;
    return boundFunction;
  }

  console.warn('`Function.prototype.bind` has been patched!');
})();

function foo() {
  console.log(this);
}
let object = {
  a: 'bind me'
};
let bar = foo.bind(object);

console.log('\'this\' object of bar: ', bar.boundThis);
console.log(`(object === bar.boundThis) =>`, object === bar.boundThis);
```

**Note:** Only the objects created after patching will have `boundThis` property.